# Random function does not print the text in the dictionary

Tags: python

I am making a mistake in this random function that should print out a random string from within the dictionary, but due to a mistake it only prints *{}*.

I tried a lot of things but the end result is always the same, here is the code:

```
import random


random10 = ""
lda_10 = {
    1: "bahria town - overseas A",
    2: "bahria town - awais qarni block",
    3: "bahria town - shaheen block",
    4: "bahria town - shaheen block extension",
    5: "bahria town - Ghouri block",
    6: "bahria town - takbeer block",
    7: "bahria town - Gulbahar Block",
    8: "bahria town - Nargis Block",
    9: "bahria town - Iris Block",
    10: "bahria town - JASMINE block",
    11: "bahria town - Gulmohar block",
    12: "bahria town - block cc",
    13: "bahria town - Chambeli block",
    14: "bahria town - tulip block",
    15: "bahria town - janiper block",
    16: "bahria town - Overseas b",
    17: "bahria town - block dd",
    18: "bahria town - rafi block",
    19: "bahria town - iqbal block",
    20: "bahria town - shershah block",
    21: "bahria town - talha block",
    22: "bahria town - johar block",
    23: "bahria town - quaid block",
    24: "bahria town - Ghaznavi block",
    25: "bahria town - sikandar block",
    26: "bahria town - tipu sultan block",
    27: "bahria town - overseas A",
    28: "bahria town - overseas A",
    29: "bahria town - overseas A",
    30: "bahria town - awais qarni block",
    31: "bahria town - shaheen block",
    32: "bahria town - shaheen block",
    33: "bahria town - shaheen block",
    34: "bahria town - shaheen block extension",
    35: "bahria town - shaheen block extension",
    36: "bahria town - shaheen block extension",
    37: "bahria town - Ghouri block",
    38: "bahria town - takbeer block",
    39: "bahria town - takbeer block",
    40: "bahria town - takbeer block",
    41: "bahria town - Gulbahar Block",
    42: "bahria town - Gulbahar Block",
    43: "bahria town - Gulbahar Block",
    44: "bahria town - Nargis Block",
    45: "bahria town - Iris Block",
    46: "bahria town - Iris Block",
    47: "bahria town - Iris Block",
    48: "bahria town - JASMINE block",
    49: "bahria town - JASMINE block",
    50: "bahria town - JASMINE block",
    51: "bahria town - Gulmohar block",
    52: "bahria town - Gulmohar block",
    53: "bahria town - Gulmohar block",
    54: "bahria town - block cc",
    55: "bahria town - block cc",
    56: "bahria town - block cc",
    }


def R_10():
    random.choice(list(lda_10.values()))==random10

R_10()
print(random10)
```

Comment: You `print(random10)` - where exactly did you expect `random10` to change?

Comment: by location i meant the string from with the dictionary

Comment: i expect random10 to change in the def R_10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def R_10():
    global random10
    random10 = random.choice(list(lda_10.values()))

R_10()
print(random10)
```

Comment: fixed u got to wait 8 min before i can accept the correct answere